# Questions about APNS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented the APNS in my app. But I have two questions about it.

1. How to make the badge self-increase? In my app, it is always set to 1 now.
2. If a push notification arrives when the app is in foreground, as far as I know, I need to implement a altert view and play a sound by my self. In this case, is there any way to play the system default notification sound, i.e. when user change it in settings, it will change automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can increment the badge count as wasim described but it will only work if  you app is in foreground, so for displaying correct badge count your server has to push correct badge number.

for playing default system notification sound when app is in foreground I dont think there is any APIs for that, for that you have put the sound file in your bundle and play that sound when notification receives.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppDelegate.m` use the following function:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    badge_value+=[[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"]intValue];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = badge_value;
}
```

where, badge_value is an integer that stores the badge value.

Comment: But this method is only called when the app is running.

Comment: this is for your first question and for the second one i dont think you can receive push notification in foreground. for that you need to do something you mention in the question(alert view etc..). hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I mean is didReceiveRemoteNotification won't be fired if the app is not running. So it won't change the badge in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in all apps, the unread notification counts are maintained in the server. When the server sends a push notification to a particular device token ***server sends the badge count along with the payload*.**

Your server logic needs to keep track of the proper badge count and send it appropriately.

```
{
    "aps" :  
    {
        "alert" : "Your notification message",
        "badge" : badgecount ,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    }
}
```